# Using wordpress get_option on plugin to retrieve a text value and display it

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

The $options variable holds my wordpress plugin options. I've seen people print_r but I'm not sure how to just echo it in a  tag for instance.

```
$options = get_option('simpledir_options', array() );

print_r($options);
```

This outputs:

```
Array ( [custom_css_styles] => disable 
[custom_css_textarea] => a{color:hotpink;} )
```

How can I just get the css value of a{color:hotpink;}?

Comment: That's an [associative array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) so this will do: `$options['custom_css_textarea']`. This is basic PHP programming, please try to do at least some research before asking this kind of questions here.

Answer (score 0):

you need to load 'wp-config.php' properly to load 'get_option' function into a page. like:

```
  require_once '../../../wp-config.php';
```